# Need advice on unit testing method which is using "dozer.map" method

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, dozer

I have an empModel and empDto object. In an spring boot app, I am making a service call to get employee model by Id. In the method, empModel is obtained from database by making a service call. Dozermapper populates the DTO and returns the dto. DozerMapper is injected to the controller .

Facing difficulty in unit testing the method. 
I am able to mock the service using when/thenReturn. However, I am unable to mock the dozerMapper as its a method with void return. What would be the right approach to unit test the method?

```
  @Inject
  public Controller(DozerBeanMapper dozerBeanMapper, EmployeeService service){
    this.dozerBeanMapper = dozerBeanMapper;
    this.service = service;
  }

  @GetMapping("/{id}")
  public EmpDto getEmployeeById(@PathVariable long id){
    EmpModel empModel = service.getEmployeeById(id);
    EmpDto empDto = new EmpDto();
    dozerBeanMapper.map(empModel,empDto);
    return empDto;
  }
```

Comment: There are different ways to mock behaviour of void methods. This is a good reference : https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-void-methods

Comment: show how you have written your test classes and mocks

Comment: @MukulGoel. I checked the link and it seems that doAnswer() would be appropriate to use. By using it, I am assuming i can mimic the behaviour of the mapper method so that the test would pass and would not get NPE. is that correct understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Dozer will create the EmpDto if you call the map method passing the EmpDto class as the second argument. It returns the EmpDto instance, which is easy to mock

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public EmpDto getEmployeeById(@PathVariable long id){
    EmpModel empModel = service.getEmployeeById(id);
    return dozerBeanMapper.map(empModel,EmpDto.class);
}
```